# How do you restart Rails under Mongrel, without stopping and starting Mongrel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongrel

Is there a way to restart the Rails app (e.g. when you've changed a plugin/config file) while Mongrel is running. Or alternatively quickly restart Mongrel. Mongrel gives these hints that you can but how do you do it?

** Signals ready.  TERM => stop.  USR2 => restart.  INT => stop (no restart).

** Rails signals registered.  HUP => reload (without restart).  It might not work well.

Answer (score 5):

You can add the -c option if the config for your app's cluster is elsewhere:

```
mongrel_rails cluster::restart -c /path/to/config
```

Answer (score 5):

1st discover the current mongrel pid path with something like:

> >ps axf | fgrep mongrel

you will see a process line like:

**ruby /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/swiftiply-0.6.1.1/bin/mongrel_rails start -p 3000 -a 0.0.0.0 -e development -P /home/xxyyzz/rails/myappname/tmp/pids/mongrel.pid -d**

Take the '-P /home/xxyyzz/rails/myappname/tmp/pids/mongrel.pid' part and use it like this:

> >mongrel_rails restart -P  /home/xxyyzz/rails/myappname/tmp/pids/mongrel.pid

**Sending USR2 to Mongrel at PID 18481...Done.**

I use this to recover from the dreaded "Broken pipe" to MySQL problem.

Answer (score 4):

in your rails home directory

```
mongrel_rails cluster::restart
```

Answer (score 3):

For example,

```
killall -USR2 mongrel_rails
```